# Error handling in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do you handle errors in SQLAlchemy? I am relatively new to SQLAlchemy and do not know yet.

Before I used SQLAlchemy, I would do things like

```
status = db.query("INSERT INTO users ...")
if (!status):
    raise Error, db.error
```

But now I am coding in SQLAlchemy and I do things like

```
user = User('Boda Cydo')
session.add(user)
session.commit()
```

No error checking whatsoever!

I do not like this coding style without error checking at all.

Please advice on how to check and handle errors in SQLAlchemy!

Sincerely, Boda Cydo.

Comment: Take a look at example at sqlalchemy.org
http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueConstraintExceptionHandling

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Your example says:

```
status = db.query("INSERT INTO users ...")
if (!status):
    raise Error, db.error
```

That seems to mean that you want to raise an exception if there's some error on the query (with `raise Error, db.error`). However sqlalchemy already does that for you - so

```
user = User('Boda Cydo')
session.add(user)
session.commit()
```

Is just the same. The check-and-raise part is already inside SQLAlchemy.

Here is a list of the errors sqlalchemy itself can raise, taken from `help(sqlalchemy.exc)` and `help(sqlalchemy.orm.exc)`:

- `sqlalchemy.exc`:

  - `ArgumentError` - Raised when an invalid or conflicting function argument is supplied.
    This error generally corresponds to construction time state errors.
  - `CircularDependencyError` - Raised by topological sorts when a circular dependency is detected
  - `CompileError` - Raised when an error occurs during SQL compilation
  - `ConcurrentModificationError`
  - `DBAPIError` - Raised when the execution of a database operation fails.
    If the error-raising operation occured in the execution of a SQL
    statement, that statement and its parameters will be available on
    the exception object in the `statement` and `params` attributes.
    The wrapped exception object is available in the `orig` attribute.
    Its type and properties are DB-API implementation specific.
  - `DataError` Wraps a DB-API `DataError`.
  - `DatabaseError` - Wraps a DB-API `DatabaseError`.
  - `DisconnectionError` - A disconnect is detected on a raw DB-API connection. 
    be raised by a `PoolListener` so that the host pool forces a disconnect.
  - `FlushError`
  - `IdentifierError` - Raised when a schema name is beyond the max character limit
  - `IntegrityError` - Wraps a DB-API `IntegrityError`.
  - `InterfaceError` - Wraps a DB-API `InterfaceError`.
  - `InternalError` - Wraps a DB-API `InternalError`.
  - `InvalidRequestError` - SQLAlchemy was asked to do something it can't do. This error generally corresponds to runtime state errors.
  - `NoReferenceError` - Raised by `ForeignKey` to indicate a reference cannot be resolved.
  - `NoReferencedColumnError` - Raised by `ForeignKey` when the referred `Column` cannot be located.
  - `NoReferencedTableError` - Raised by `ForeignKey` when the referred `Table` cannot be located.
  - `NoSuchColumnError` - A nonexistent column is requested from a `RowProxy`.
  - `NoSuchTableError` - Table does not exist or is not visible to a connection.
  - `NotSupportedError` - Wraps a DB-API `NotSupportedError`.
  - `OperationalError` - Wraps a DB-API `OperationalError`.
  - `ProgrammingError` - Wraps a DB-API `ProgrammingError`.
  - `SADeprecationWarning` - Issued once per usage of a deprecated API.
  - `SAPendingDeprecationWarning` - Issued once per usage of a deprecated API.
  - `SAWarning` - Issued at runtime.
  - `SQLAlchemyError` - Generic error class.
  - `SQLError` - Raised when the execution of a database operation fails.
  - `TimeoutError` - Raised when a connection pool times out on getting a connection.
  - `UnboundExecutionError` - SQL was attempted without a database connection to execute it on.
  - `UnmappedColumnError`
- `sqlalchemy.orm.exc`:

  - `ConcurrentModificationError` - Rows have been modified outside of the unit of work.
  - `FlushError` - A invalid condition was detected during `flush()`.
  - `MultipleResultsFound` - A single database result was required but more than one were found.
  - `NoResultFound` - A database result was required but none was found.
  - `ObjectDeletedError` - A `refresh()` operation failed to re-retrieve an object's row.
  - `UnmappedClassError` - A mapping operation was requested for an unknown class.
  - `UnmappedColumnError` - Mapping operation was requested on an unknown column.
  - `UnmappedError` - TODO
  - `UnmappedInstanceError` - A mapping operation was requested for an unknown instance.

Answer (score 46):

I tried this and it showed me the specific error message.

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError

try:
# try something

except SQLAlchemyError as e:
  error = str(e.__dict__['orig'])
  return error
```

Hope this helps

Comment: error = str(e.orig) works as well

Answer (score 12):

To get type of exception, you can simply call :

Firstly, import exc from sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import exc
```

To catch types of errors:

```
    try:
        # any query
    except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print(type(e))
```

This will give you exception type:
 **Output:**

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError'>
<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError'>
```

Answer (score 1):

My two cents on handling errors in SQLAlchemy: a simple python's try-except will not work as MySQL is persistent. For example, if you try to insert a record to the database but it is a duplicate, the program will take the exception route but MySQL will stop based on the insert command that did not go through. Avoid try-except in combination with SQLAlchemy commands or be prepared for these situations.

Answer (score -2):

SQLAlchemy will raise an exception on error....

Comment: The exceptions are in two different modules -- sqlalchemy.exc and sqlalchemy.orm.exc.

Exceptions are automatically raised when an error occurs, unlike the code in your example where you have to do that yourself...